# По какому принципу сохраняются текстовые файлы на жестком диске?

Tags: файлы

Я себе представляю текстовой файл как последовательность битов, которая интерпретируется как последовательность символов одной длинни. Каждый символ принадлежит одной и той самой кодировке.
Но как сохраняется форматированный текст ( с жирными и курсивными символами)? В области памяти которая отводится на один символ кроме кода данного символа есть еще биты которые идентифицируют форматирования этого символа? А такие элементы как абзацы, заголовки, маркирование?

Comment: Почитайте про HTML и RTF, например

Comment: В разных программах/форматах по разному сохраняется.

Comment: "биты" это "байты"? погрешности перевода?

Comment: @Igor я имел в виду биты, хотя байты тоже подойдут

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения ОС все файлы на диске сохраняются одинаково.

Форматированный текст имеет логическую структуру, в которой кроме собственно символов текста содержится информация о том, как этот текст надо отображать (рисовать) на экране (или на принтере).

Т.е. разница между типами файлов заключается  *в интерпретации последовательности байт* прикладной программой.

Comment: Следовательно, текстовой файл не обезательно содержит биты в таком виде: 
<формат символа1><символ1>, <формат символа2><символ2> і т.д.?
Он может содержать биты в таком виде: <абзац><формат символа1><символ1>, <формат символа2><символ2> і т.д.?

Comment: @Тарас, текстовый файл принципиально ничем от бинарного не отличается. Только нашим восприятием. Ну, в винде, если открыть (fopen) файл без `"b"`, то  `\r\n`, хранимые в файле будут при передаче в программу заменяться на `\n` (и `\n` при выводе заменяться на `\r\n`)

Answer (score 0):

Да  кодируется особыми символами или группами символов. Например в txt 0D(16-ричный код) - возврат каретки, при вызове которого указатель переходит к левому крайнему положению в строке, 0A- переход на новую строку. Эти 2 символа можно увидеть в конце каждой строки файла. 
  Другие форматы представляют надстройки на этот простой формат. Например в docx курсив и жирный текст кодируется xml тегами- попробуй изменить разрешение docx на zip, а потом открыть архиватором- увидишь группу xml документов, открыв которые увидишь как кодируются абзацы и прочее.
 WinHex поможет посмотреть что какими символами кодируется в txt.